# write on multiple table with similar map reduce

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

On HBase I have a table, `TABLE-A`, which has timestamp on its row-key. Since `TABLE-A` is extremely large with many data having same timestamp, I wanna aggregate the table on basis on minute, hour and day. I can extract timestamp in MyMapper along with column items and pass the resolute timestamp along with column items to MyReducer to perform operations and create TABLE-A-Minute. Now to create hour and day, I don't want to go back to `TABLE-A` but do it  during minute-aggregation since they are `60,3600,86400` seconds.

How can I do it in `HBase` as `TableMapReduceUtil` takes `MyMapper.Class` and `MyReducer.Class` and there is no way to differentiate which resolution is coming from Mapper, even if I try creating multiple Reducer Classes. I can only think of creating multiple Jobs but it still won't affect Mapper Class.